# Is it possible to NOT dismiss a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview

The UIAlertviewDelegate protocol has several optional methods including:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

This would seem to suggest that not all button clicks actually dismiss the alert view. However I see no way of configuring the alert view to NOT automatically dismiss with any button press.

Do I have to create a subclass to accomplish this?

Why would the UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol have:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

AND

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

If it didn't optionally support not dismissing the alert view with each button click?

Brief Aside:
I realize what UIAlertView was designed for. But my purpose is to allow the user to copy some text to the paste board before the app exits (which happens automatically when the alert view is dismissed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. Subclass `UIAlertView` and then overload `-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`, e.g.

```
@implementation MyAlertView 
-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated {
   if (buttonIndex should not dismiss the alert)
      return;
   [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
}
@end
```

---

**Unofficially** you can define a

```
-(void)alertSheet:(UIAlertSheet*)sheet buttonClicked:(id)button;
```

method to the delegate which will make it bypass `-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`, but it's **undocumented**, so I don't know whether it's suitable for you.

Comment: Thats what I am doing now. But because of the available delegate methods, it seems like I shouldn't have to. Oh well…

Comment: Hmm… interesting. Too bad they have crcked down on using undocumented APIs.

Comment: But how to dismiss this custom alert after that with another button. or from code? I call dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: method but alertView do not disappear.

Comment: This no longer works in iOS 7 unfortunately. `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` is no longer called after the UIAlertViewDelegate callbacks, so overriding with an empty method implementation is no longer a solution.

Comment: any alternative for ios 7 ?

Comment: How do I do the same on siwft?

Answer (score 3):

`willPresentAlertView:`, `didPresentAlertView:`, `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`, and `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` are for tracking the start and end of UIAlertView's animations.

Applications that don't need to track UIAlertView's animations can simply use `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.  The docs for that method say "the receiver is automatically dismissed after this method is invoked."

Comment: Thanks, I missed that last piece of text in the docs. Still seems like overkill to have that extra method, since it essentially the same as willPresentAlertView…

Comment: @Darren: Thanks and lot in ios7 alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex: this method call twice. but your solution save my day..

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion: There's no reason to keep alertView. Even if you wanna keep it, just think about "re-show" it, by keeping a reference, then call [alertView show] ==> **NO NEED TO SUBCLASS ANYTHING**. Good news, huh?

Comment: This works. Albeit there is a slight flicker when you redisplay the popup.

Answer (score 1):

> **WARNING**
>
> From some sources I have heard that few app have got rejected
> following this process. I was lucky in my case during iOS6 so I am
> showing code here. Use on your own risk :-/

Subclassing is the best way. Create a `bool` flag for alert should stay or not.

**This is the Subclass of `UIAlertView`**

```
//
//  UICustomAlertView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UICustomAlertView : UIAlertView
{
    
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL dontDisppear;
@end

//
//  UICustomAlertView.m
//

#import "UICustomAlertView.h"

@implementation UICustomAlertView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if(self.dontDisppear)
        return;
    [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
}
@end
```

**And this is how I used it into my code**

```
if(![txtUsername.text isEqualToString:@"admin"] && ![txtPassword.text isEqualToString:@"admin"])
{
     alertLogin.dontDisppear = YES;
     alertLogin.message = NSLocalizedString(@"my_alert", nil);
}
else
{
     alertLogin.dontDisppear = NO;
     // proceed
}
```

Comment: I have given a -1, the reason being because of `"The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified"` in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html so implementing your way would be going against the Apple Documentation and Review process so would get their app rejected. This has been the way for a few years now so at the time of you answering this will have been an incorrect answer.

Comment: May be but my app approved last year (iOS 6).

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't mean it is right. I submitted an app before I knew about this as well and it got through the initial review process then was rejected when I submitted an update. The Apple review team are only human they can miss things. I know though they are being more strict with iOS 7 though. However my -1 was purely because this answer goes against the Apple documentation and you don't warn of it. If you warn of this I will happily remove my -1

Comment: I'm happy with that I have removed my -1

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "MLAlertView.h"

@implementation MLAlertView


-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated {
}

-(void)dismissNow:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  {
     [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
}
```