# Stop UIAlertView from dismissing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uialertview

Can you stop UIAlertView from dismissing?

I want based on what button is pressed, to either animate adding a UITextField, or dismiss it. But I can't add a text field after the alert is dismissed.

Comment: No, implement your own alert view with the desired functionality...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051402/is-it-possible-to-not-dismiss-a-uialertview

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the UIAlertViewDelegate method :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

and based on the button index you can perform your custom action.

Otherwise you should either create your own alertview class or subclass UIAlertView.

If you choose to subclass you can override the method :

```
-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to avoid dismissing the alertView if a specific button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add a `UITextField` after the `UIActionSheet` is dismissed then add a method  that when the ActionSheet gets dismissed then call the method for the TextField.