# How to turn off dismiss UIAlertView when click UIButton in alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is correct way to turn off dismiss UIAlertView when click button in UIAlertView. I want to check if not have string in UITextField when click button not dismiss the view.

```
  -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
      //Add alert delegate
    if (alertView.tag == kDeleteAlertTag)
    {

        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self.emails removeObjectAtIndex:currentIndex];
            [self.plistReader saveToPlistName:kPlistEmails fromArray:self.emails];
            [self.tblEmails reloadData];
        }
    }

    // remove email alert delegate
    if (alertView.tag == kAddEmailTag)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {

            // get text Input Alert
            UITextField * emailInputTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

            // get string from text Alert
            NSString *textInput = [emailInputTextField text];

            if (self.emails== nil) {
                self.emails = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            }
            if ([textInput isEqualToString:@""]) {
                NSLog(@"Not have string");
            }else
            if ([KUtils NSStringIsValidEmail:textInput] == YES)
            {
                [self.emails addObject:textInput];

                // save to plist and reload table
                [self.plistReader saveToPlistName:kPlistEmails fromArray:self.emails];
                [self.tblEmails reloadData];

            }else if([KUtils NSStringIsValidEmail:textInput] == NO)
            {

                // not dismiss alert in hre
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051402/is-it-possible-to-not-dismiss-a-uialertview

Comment: This no longer works in iOS 7 unfortunately.

Comment: how many alert are used in that page

Comment: Why don't you create your own alert view?

Comment: use **tags** for alrtview

Comment: i used tag for each alert, but when click OK the alert is dismiss and i want if not valid email the alert not dismiss. Thanks

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated, consider using UIAlertController instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController . It is conceptually different from UIAlertView and might better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't validate against the string validate against the text field

```
 if (emailInputTextField.text && emailInputTextField.text.length > 0)
{
//do something 
}
else
{
//All fields are required UIAlert here
}
```

**Edit**

You can also try:

```
if ([emailInputTextField.text length] != 0) {
//Do something
}
else {
//All fields are required UIAlert here
}
```

Comment: i try but alertview still dismiss when click to button

Comment: @apple8 see my edit. Either way it's the correct way to find empty text fields. You just have to properly nest them